# css shapes polygon does not move along with element when changing the position of the element

Tags: css

so i'm trying to move the polygon created using css3's shape-outside property along with the image element that i'm giving a relative position. However, it seems the polygon does not move along with the element, instead it just stays put at the original position of the element.

I tried just created a polygon using svg, creating a clip-path using css and tried position the polygon itself, but so far no luck. the problem is displayed in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/rasenguy/pen/PVmmPW).

```
<style>
    section {
      width:95%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }

    section img {
      width: 50rem;
      float: right;
      position: relative;
      left: 6rem;
      z-index: -1;
      shape-outside: polygon(63.5% 21.85%, 67.4% -0.2%, 77% 13.35%, 87.5% 16.8%, 94.65% 44.95%, 95.25% 88.45%, 37.15% 95.75%, 3.75% 75.1%, 2.25% 65.2%, 47.5% 44.35%, 45.5% 16.4%);
     -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(63.5% 21.85%, 67.4% -0.2%, 77% 13.35%, 87.5% 16.8%, 94.65% 44.95%, 95.25% 88.45%, 37.15% 95.75%, 3.75% 75.1%, 2.25% 65.2%, 47.5% 44.35%, 45.5% 16.4%);
    }
</style>
<body>
  <section>
    <img src="https://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/14195-Cute-cat-and-kitten-white-background.jpg" alt="" >
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi necessitatibus illum tempore aliquid possimus ea maiores eligendi, id distinctio! Quas, aut vel. Culpa consectetur labore in voluptatum repudiandae cum officiis! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Modi eveniet aperiam maxime, maiores, vel voluptatum quaerat accusamus temporibus, fuga omnis ullam eligendi. Eligendi nulla eaque, maiores earum voluptas sunt excepturi? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error hic iusto sit, animi quaerat commodi sequi accusamus beatae illum expedita quisquam cupiditate amet magnam. Odit assumenda eaque aliquid mollitia omnis! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores veniam numquam adipisci eius quisquam sed! Nulla harum omnis quis blanditiis? Inventore, possimus similique veniam optio perferendis perspiciatis. Modi, accusamus aperiam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro, iure laborum eum nisi commodi ipsa architecto esse itaque cumque quis dolorem perferendis iusto harum, placeat nam totam repudiandae alias minima? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus blanditiis quis consequatur cumque minus fugiat cum similique excepturi sunt placeat aspernatur expedita, facere commodi officia deleniti praesentium dolores voluptas doloremque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam maxime repellat id magnam dicta rem optio ex soluta odit! Ducimus, expedita et iusto mollitia in delectus officia asperiores ratione nulla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat quibusdam error earum. Aliquam sapiente autem ab perspiciatis vitae ipsum ea iusto? Sequi autem voluptatem, a libero necessitatibus error provident ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod et perferendis a ab assumenda adipisci consequuntur consectetur architecto voluptatem! Dolorum facilis nam itaque natus blanditiis perspiciatis, minus incidunt doloremque consequuntur? Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique optio beatae eos error ea unde, explicabo alias voluptates excepturi assumenda placeat quis libero ipsum, officiis, consectetur repellendus laborum amet rem. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat sequi quas ad, nisi exercitationem dolorem, blanditiis nihil nobis incidunt nemo omnis recusandae architecto pariatur aliquam inventore est eveniet esse. Aperiam. Aliquam sapiente autem ab perspiciatis vitae ipsum ea iusto? Sequi autem voluptatem, a libero necessitatibus error provident ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod et perferendis a ab assumenda adipisci consequuntur consectetur architecto voluptatem! Dolorum facilis nam itaque natus blanditiis perspiciatis, minus incidunt doloremque consequuntur? Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique optio beatae eos error ea unde, explicabo alias voluptates excepturi assumenda placeat quis libero ipsum, officiis, consectetur repellendus laborum amet rem. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat sequi quas ad, nisi exercitationem dolorem, blanditiis nihil nobis incidunt nemo omnis recusandae architecto pariatur aliquam inventore est eveniet esse. Aperiam. Aliquam sapiente autem ab perspiciatis vitae ipsum ea iusto? Sequi autem voluptatem, a libero necessitatibus error provident ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod et perferendis a ab assumenda adipisci consequuntur consectetur architecto voluptatem! Dolorum facilis nam itaque natus blanditiis perspiciatis, minus incidunt doloremque consequuntur? Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique optio beatae eos error ea unde, explicabo alias voluptates excepturi assumenda placeat quis libero ipsum, officiis, consectetur repellendus laborum amet rem. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat sequi quas ad, nisi exercitationem dolorem, blanditiis nihil nobis incidunt nemo omnis recusandae architecto pariatur aliquam inventore est eveniet esse. Aperiam. Aliquam sapiente autem ab perspiciatis vitae ipsum ea iusto? Sequi autem voluptatem, a libero necessitatibus error provident ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod et perferendis a ab assumenda adipisci consequuntur consectetur architecto voluptatem! Dolorum facilis nam itaque natus blanditiis perspiciatis, minus incidunt doloremque consequuntur? Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique optio beatae eos error ea unde, explicabo alias voluptates excepturi assumenda placeat quis libero ipsum, officiis, consectetur repellendus laborum amet rem. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat sequi quas ad, nisi exercitationem dolorem, blanditiis nihil nobis incidunt nemo omnis recusandae architecto pariatur aliquam inventore est eveniet esse. Aperiam.Aliquam sapiente autem ab perspiciatis vitae ipsum ea iusto? Sequi autem voluptatem, a libero necessitatibus error provident ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod et perferendis a ab assumenda adipisci consequuntur consectetur architecto voluptatem! Dolorum facilis nam itaque natus blanditiis perspiciatis, minus incidunt doloremque consequuntur? Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique optio beatae eos error ea unde, explicabo alias voluptates excepturi assumenda placeat quis libero ipsum, officiis, consectetur repellendus laborum amet rem. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat sequi quas ad, nisi exercitationem dolorem, blanditiis nihil nobis incidunt nemo omnis recusandae architecto pariatur aliquam inventore est eveniet esse. Aperiam. Aliquam sapiente autem ab perspiciatis vitae ipsum ea iusto? Sequi autem voluptatem, a libero necessitatibus error provident ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod et perferendis a ab assumenda adipisci consequuntur consectetur architecto voluptatem! Dolorum facilis nam itaque natus blanditiis perspiciatis, minus incidunt doloremque consequuntur? Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique optio beatae eos error ea unde, explicabo alias voluptates excepturi assumenda placeat quis libero ipsum, officiis, consectetur repellendus laborum amet rem. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat sequi quas ad, nisi exercitationem dolorem, blanditiis nihil nobis incidunt nemo omnis recusandae architecto pariatur aliquam inventore est eveniet esse. Aperiam. Aliquam sapiente autem ab perspiciatis vitae ipsum ea iusto? Sequi autem voluptatem, a libero necessitatibus error provident ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod et perferendis a ab assumenda adipisci consequuntur consectetur architecto voluptatem! Dolorum facilis nam itaque natus blanditiis perspiciatis, minus incidunt doloremque consequuntur? Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique optio beatae eos error ea unde, explicabo alias voluptates excepturi assumenda placeat quis libero ipsum, officiis, consectetur repellendus laborum amet rem. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat sequi quas ad, nisi exercitationem dolorem, blanditiis nihil nobis incidunt nemo omnis recusandae architecto pariatur aliquam inventore est eveniet esse. Aperiam.</p>
  </section>
</body>
```

I would like to know if there is a workaround to this problem where the polygon moves along with the image. so in this case it would have moved around 6 rem to the right, along with the image.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using left, use margin rigth with a negative value.

I have added a change on the value on hover to make more visible that it really works

```css
section {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

section img {
  width: 50rem;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -6rem;
  z-index: -100;
  shape-outside: polygon(63.5% 21.85%, 67.4% -0.2%, 77% 13.35%, 87.5% 16.8%, 94.65% 44.95%, 95.25% 88.45%, 37.15% 95.75%, 3.75% 75.1%, 2.25% 65.2%, 47.5% 44.35%, 45.5% 16.4%);
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(63.5% 21.85%, 67.4% -0.2%, 77% 13.35%, 87.5% 16.8%, 94.65% 44.95%, 95.25% 88.45%, 37.15% 95.75%, 3.75% 75.1%, 2.25% 65.2%, 47.5% 44.35%, 45.5% 16.4%);
  transition: margin 2s;
}

section:hover img {
  margin-right: -20rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="https://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/14195-Cute-cat-and-kitten-white-background.jpg" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi necessitatibus illum tempore aliquid possimus ea maiores eligendi, id distinctio! Quas, aut vel. Culpa consectetur labore in voluptatum repudiandae cum officiis! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    consectetur, adipisicing elit. Modi eveniet aperiam maxime, maiores, vel voluptatum quaerat accusamus temporibus, fuga omnis ullam eligendi. Eligendi nulla eaque, maiores earum voluptas sunt excepturi? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Error hic iusto sit, animi quaerat commodi sequi accusamus beatae illum expedita quisquam cupiditate amet magnam. Odit assumenda eaque aliquid mollitia omnis! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores veniam numquam adipisci
    eius quisquam sed! Nulla harum omnis quis blanditiis? Inventore, possimus similique veniam optio perferendis perspiciatis. Modi, accusamus aperiam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro, iure laborum eum nisi commodi ipsa
    architecto esse itaque cumque quis dolorem perferendis iusto harum, placeat nam totam repudiandae alias minima? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus blanditiis quis consequatur cumque minus fugiat cum similique excepturi
    sunt placeat aspernatur expedita, facere commodi officia deleniti praesentium dolores voluptas doloremque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam maxime repellat id magnam dicta rem optio ex soluta odit! Ducimus, expedita et
    iusto mollitia in delectus officia asperiores ratione nulla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat quibusdam error earum. Aliquam sapiente autem ab perspiciatis vitae ipsum ea iusto? Sequi autem voluptatem, a libero necessitatibus
    error provident ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod et perferendis a ab assumenda adipisci consequuntur consectetur architecto voluptatem! Dolorum facilis nam itaque natus blanditiis perspiciatis, minus incidunt doloremque
    consequuntur? Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique optio beatae eos error ea unde, explicabo alias voluptates excepturi assumenda placeat quis libero ipsum, officiis, consectetur repellendus laborum amet rem. Lorem ipsum,
    dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat sequi quas ad, nisi exercitationem dolorem, blanditiis nihil nobis incidunt nemo omnis recusandae architecto pariatur aliquam inventore est eveniet esse. Aperiam. Aliquam sapiente autem ab perspiciatis
    vitae ipsum ea iusto? Sequi autem voluptatem, a libero necessitatibus error provident ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod et perferendis a ab assumenda adipisci consequuntur consectetur architecto voluptatem! Dolorum
    facilis nam itaque natus blanditiis perspiciatis, minus incidunt doloremque consequuntur? Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique optio beatae eos error ea unde, explicabo alias voluptates excepturi assumenda placeat quis
    libero ipsum, officiis, consectetur repellendus laborum amet rem. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat sequi quas ad, nisi exercitationem dolorem, blanditiis nihil nobis incidunt nemo omnis recusandae architecto pariatur
    aliquam inventore est eveniet esse. Aperiam. Aliquam sapiente autem ab perspiciatis vitae ipsum ea iusto? Sequi autem voluptatem, a libero necessitatibus error provident ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod et perferendis
    a ab assumenda adipisci consequuntur consectetur architecto voluptatem! Dolorum facilis nam itaque natus blanditiis perspiciatis, minus incidunt doloremque consequuntur? Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique optio beatae
    eos error ea unde, explicabo alias voluptates excepturi assumenda placeat quis libero ipsum, officiis, consectetur repellendus laborum amet rem. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat sequi quas ad, nisi exercitationem dolorem,
    blanditiis nihil nobis incidunt nemo omnis recusandae architecto pariatur aliquam inventore est eveniet esse. Aperiam. Aliquam sapiente autem ab perspiciatis vitae ipsum ea iusto? Sequi autem voluptatem, a libero necessitatibus error provident ad.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod et perferendis a ab assumenda adipisci consequuntur consectetur architecto voluptatem! Dolorum facilis nam itaque natus blanditiis perspiciatis, minus incidunt doloremque consequuntur?
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique optio beatae eos error ea unde, explicabo alias voluptates excepturi assumenda placeat quis libero ipsum, officiis, consectetur repellendus laborum amet rem. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit
    amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat sequi quas ad, nisi exercitationem dolorem, blanditiis nihil nobis incidunt nemo omnis recusandae architecto pariatur aliquam inventore est eveniet esse. Aperiam.Aliquam sapiente autem ab perspiciatis vitae
    ipsum ea iusto? Sequi autem voluptatem, a libero necessitatibus error provident ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod et perferendis a ab assumenda adipisci consequuntur consectetur architecto voluptatem! Dolorum facilis
    nam itaque natus blanditiis perspiciatis, minus incidunt doloremque consequuntur? Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique optio beatae eos error ea unde, explicabo alias voluptates excepturi assumenda placeat quis libero
    ipsum, officiis, consectetur repellendus laborum amet rem. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat sequi quas ad, nisi exercitationem dolorem, blanditiis nihil nobis incidunt nemo omnis recusandae architecto pariatur aliquam
    inventore est eveniet esse. Aperiam. Aliquam sapiente autem ab perspiciatis vitae ipsum ea iusto? Sequi autem voluptatem, a libero necessitatibus error provident ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod et perferendis a ab
    assumenda adipisci consequuntur consectetur architecto voluptatem! Dolorum facilis nam itaque natus blanditiis perspiciatis, minus incidunt doloremque consequuntur? Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique optio beatae eos
    error ea unde, explicabo alias voluptates excepturi assumenda placeat quis libero ipsum, officiis, consectetur repellendus laborum amet rem. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat sequi quas ad, nisi exercitationem dolorem,
    blanditiis nihil nobis incidunt nemo omnis recusandae architecto pariatur aliquam inventore est eveniet esse. Aperiam. Aliquam sapiente autem ab perspiciatis vitae ipsum ea iusto? Sequi autem voluptatem, a libero necessitatibus error provident ad.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod et perferendis a ab assumenda adipisci consequuntur consectetur architecto voluptatem! Dolorum facilis nam itaque natus blanditiis perspiciatis, minus incidunt doloremque consequuntur?
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique optio beatae eos error ea unde, explicabo alias voluptates excepturi assumenda placeat quis libero ipsum, officiis, consectetur repellendus laborum amet rem. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit
    amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat sequi quas ad, nisi exercitationem dolorem, blanditiis nihil nobis incidunt nemo omnis recusandae architecto pariatur aliquam inventore est eveniet esse. Aperiam.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but it does not solve the problem, as when the image is fully extended to right you see that there is a larger gap then initially between the head of the kittens and text. 

I think i partly solved it by removing the position property entirely and putting the image inside a div and the changing its positioning the image margin. i don't know if this is the best solution though so going to wait and see if someone as done it differentely, vals